# How to send a string from a application to DAL plugin using IPC on MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, ipc, appleevents, coremediaio

I have a [`CoreMediaIO`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html) based `DAL plugin` written in [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)) which currently poll a website to get that string. Which is not a good approach.

I want to send that string to DAL plugin via [Operating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) supported [IPC(Inter Process Communication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

But there are many ways to do IPC on `MacOS` like

- `Apple Events`
- `Distributed Notifications in Cocoa`
- `BSD Notifications`
- `Transferring Raw Data With CFMessagePort`
- `Communicating With BSD Sockets`
- `Communicating With BSD Pipes`
- `Distributed Objects`
- `Pasteboard`
- `XPC`

In my case I just want `one way communication` from a `application` to `DAL Plugin`.

I am new to MacOS development so not sure which approch will be efficiant and best for my case of **one way comminucation from Application to DAL Plugin**?