# Simplest client server example code using IPC using XPC using swift on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, client-server, ipc, xpc

I am from a [C/C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), [Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) background and recently started learning development on `MacOS` using [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)).

I want simple [IPC(Inter Process Communication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) between two [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), let's call them `server process` and `client process`.

I could not find any simple example showing use of [XPC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xpc) for `IPC`. Let me try to put my thinking and what I am trying to build.

Suppose I have `server_process.swift`

```swift
// This is XPC Server

import Foundation

func run_server_loop() {
    // I guess I have to use NSXPCListener e.g. XPC Service
}

func on_message(message) {
    // I have received message from client_server.swift
    // do whatever can be done with this message
    // send reply to client_server.swift

    if(message == "ping") {
        send("pong")
    } else {
        send("command not supported")
    }
}

// run loop to start listener
run_server_loop()
```

I would need `client_server.swift`

```swift
import Foundation

// This is XPC Client

func some_way_to_connect() {
    // some way to connect to server process
}

// connect to server which is running on server_process.swift
client = some_way_to_connect()

// send a message to server
client.send("ping")
```

I put my thoughts in [pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode).

How can I achieve such communication using XPC using Swift?

Comment: Technically speaking, XPC *only* does IPC ^_^ , typically between a main app some helper service, whose lifecycle is managed by XPC. I think what you mean is that you would like to use it for some kind of peer-to-peer communication between existing processes of yours, is that correct?

Comment: @Alexander: Yes you are right I could have right `using XPC` instead of `using IPC using XPC`. but I wrote intentionally to keep things more informative. Someone who dont know `XPC` will get to know that its related to IPC :-)

Comment: @Alexander: My real requirement is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233948/how-to-send-a-string-from-a-application-to-dal-plugin-using-ipc-on-macos

Comment: Oh I've seen that question before, I already had it up-voted :). From what I can tell, XPC is catered exclusively to a client-server style of communication, where a large part of its "value add " is to manage the life cycle of an XPC or Mach service for you. I don't know if that's compatible with a `DAL plugin` (device abstraction layer plugin? I don't know what this is, and I couldn't find any docs on this), where I suspect the DAL plugin's life-cycle is managed for you. IIRC, XPC is quite similar to CFMessagePort, which is suited for more generalized IPC.

Comment: Preface: I'm a dummy who doesn't know much about most of these things, so verify any information I give that's operative to any design decisions you make, lol

Comment: @Alexander: Thank you so much for writing whatever you could :-)
You can see this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html